# Utilizar retorno de uma função em outra função

Tags: python, array, lista

Tenho uma função em Python que recebe um texto e retorna 2 listas, uma com todas as palavras que aparecem e a outra retorna é o numero de vezes que cada palavra aparece.

```
def frequencia(lista):
    conv = str(lista)
    plSeparadas = separa_palavras(conv)        

    listUnic = []
    listFreq = []

    for p in plSeparadas:
        if p in listUnic:
            i = listUnic.index(p)
            listFreq[i] = listFreq[i] + 1
        else:
            listUnic.append(p)
            listFreq.append(1)

            xList = listUnic
            xFreq = listFreq

    return xList, xFreq
```

Preciso utilizar esse numero de vezes (xFreq) em uma outra função para calcular o valor médio da frequência :

```
def mediaFreq(listaFrequencia):
    ordenar = sorted(listaFrequencia)
    tamanho = len(ordenar)
    media = tamanho/2
    return(media)
```

Como posso fazer isso ??

Answer (score 1):

Se o método retorna uma tupla de valores é necessário usar uma tupla para receber o retorno do mesmo.

Aplicando no seu código, seria algo como:

```
xList, xFreq = frequencia(lista)
media = mediaFreq(xFreq)
```

Exemplo:

```
def teste():
    return 'A', 'B'

x, y = teste()

print(x)  # A
print(y)  # B
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso212454)

Answer (score 1):

```
def frequencia(lista):
    conv = str(lista)
    plSeparadas = separa_palavras(conv)        

    listUnic = []
    listFreq = []

    for p in plSeparadas:
        if p in listUnic:
            i = listUnic.index(p)
            listFreq[i] = listFreq[i] + 1
        else:
            listUnic.append(p)
            listFreq.append(1)

            xList = listUnic
            xFreq = listFreq

    return xList, xFreq
def mediaFreq(listaFrequencia, xFreq):
    ordenar = sorted(listaFrequencia)
    tamanho = len(ordenar)
    media = tamanho/2
    return(media)
xList, xFreq = frequencia(lista)
media = mediaFreq(listaFrequencia, xFreq)
```

É só vc atribuir os valores de retorno da sua função frequencia à duas variáveis, as quais podem ter qualquer nome, apenas coloquei xList e xFreq pra facilitar o entendimento.

Como elas foram `RETORNADAS` da função `frequencia`, agora elas estão em escopo global e podem então, ser passadas por parâmetro para sua função `mediaFreq` da seguinte forma:  `media = mediaFreq(listaFrequencia, xFreq)`. Não podemos esquecer de alterar os parâmetros de entrada de `mediaFreq`.

Answer (score 0):

Como você compacta no return, você tem que descompactar no código main do seu script.
Por que as variantes só armazenadas na função elas tem que ser descompactadas no código principal.

Dessa forma o returno da função será armazenado nas variantes globais do código principal.

```
xList, xFreq = frequencia(lista)
```